# Adicionar tag em todas as repetições de determinada palavra

Tags: javascript, sql-insert, formatação

Vejam o código abaixo:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .format{
        color: red;
        font-style: italic;
    }
</style>

<div>
     <p>texto texto texto 'palavra-chave'. texto 'palavra-chave', texto texto.<p>
</div>
```

Dentro da `div`, ignorando tags, eu quero que sempre que for encontrado uma 'palavra-chave' colocar ela dentro de `<span class="format">`

Qual seria a melhor solução para isso usando **JavaScript puro**?

Comment: @Laerte por que deletou sua resposta?

Comment: Porque você pediu a solução em Javascript puro.

Comment: @Laerte ah sim.

Comment: Está a "mesma" (veja que coloquei aspas) questão que você postou sobre "palavras reservadas" do Javascript?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é o mesmo algoritmo

Comment: Em questão de segurança eu *pessoalmente* discordo deste método de limitar o usuário, pois existem maneiras mais eficazes e menos "limitantes" de tornar *seguro* um editor de texto online. Porém como isto atualmente foge do foco da questão *atual*, por favor teste a minha resposta.

Comment: Tens só uma div ou podem ser várias divs?

Comment: @Sergio Minha intenção é repetir esse mesmo campo diversas vezes. É um editor de Javascript na realidade, portanto é só uma div editável de texto simples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa funcionalidade é simples, dá para usar `.split().join()` ou regex para substituir o conteúdo com `.replace()`.

Na sua versão mais simples seria:

```
var editavel = document.querySelector('div[contenteditable="true"]');
var novoConteudo = '<span class="format">palavra-chave</span>';
editavel.innerHTML = editavel.innerHTML.split('palavra-chave').join(novoConteudo);
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u68b6tz8/**

Se quiseres fazer essa substituição *on the fly*, a cada nova letra inserida, então a coisa fica mais interessante. Podes juntar um *event listener* para quando uma tecla é libertada (*keyup*) e verificar o conteúdo:

```
var editavel = document.querySelector('div[contenteditable="true"]');
editavel.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    var novoConteudo = '<span class="format">palavra-chave</span>';
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.split('palavra-chave').join(novoConteudo);

});
```

O problema agora que falta resolver é o careto/cursor, que sai da posição quando o HTML é substituído. No SOen encontrei duas perguntas sobre isso onde o Tim Down responde sobre [como ler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812022/96100) e [como setar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6249440/2256325) o cursor/careto. Essas respostas não resolvem o problema diretamente mas levaram-me a esta solução:

Três passos!

**#1 -** substituir todas as palavras quando o código corre pela primeira vez. Desta maneira sabemos que quando digitar-mos só irá aparecer uma nova de cada vez.

**#2 -** Usar o replace, com função! Desta maneira podemos inserir um span e para resolver o problema do careto damos a essa span um ID secreto.

**#3 -** Assim podemos selecionar esse elemento e apontar o careto para o inicio do proximo sibling.

Aplicado a este caso o código ficaria assim:

```js
var palavraChave = 'palavra-chave';

// fazer substituições antes de começar a escrever
var editavel = document.querySelector('div[contenteditable="true"]');
var novoConteudo = '<span class="format">palavra-chave</span>';
editavel.innerHTML = editavel.innerHTML.split('palavra-chave').join(novoConteudo);

var editavel = document.querySelector('div[contenteditable="true"]');
editavel.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    var regExp = new RegExp('(' + palavraChave + ')(?!<)', 'g');
    // se não houver nada para substituir, sair
    if (!this.innerHTML.match(regExp)) return;
    var novoConteudo = this.innerHTML.replace(regExp, function () {
        // trocar o match pelo novo conteudo
        return '<span id="span_secreto">' + palavraChave + '</span>';
    });
    this.innerHTML = novoConteudo;
    // ir buscar o elemento secreto criado para lhe retirar a ID e colocar a classe
    var span = document.getElementById('span_secreto');
    span.removeAttribute('id');
    span.classList.add('format');
    colocarCareto(span);
});

function colocarCareto(node) {
    // defenir que elemento o careto deve seguir. Criar um novo placebo se o span fôr o ultimo
    var target = node.nextSibling ? node.nextSibling : (function (el) {
        var novoTextNode = document.createTextNode(' ');
        el.appendChild(novoTextNode);
        return novoTextNode
    })(node);
    // colocar o careto no inicio do proximo elemento
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(target, 1);
    range.setEnd(target, 1);
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
}
```

```css
.format {
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
}
span.format {
    color: #aad;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
    texto texto texto palavra-chave. texto palavra-chav, texto texto.
</div>
```

O código ainda precisa de mais afinações, e talvez depois dê para encurtar. Mas a ideia principal e a funcionalidade fica.