# Busca na página com JavaScript com IE

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia!

Estamos criando uma página super simples em HTML mesmo para um pequeno documento que alguns usuários irão acessar. Neste documento temos um formulário (input text) de busca que terá que retornar através de um "highlight" o que o usuário buscou. É como o uso do CTRL + F mesmo, porém através do campo de busca, pois o usuário não quer buscar com CTRL + F ou mesmo às vezes não sabe do comando. Busquei alguns JAVASCRIPT na Internet, encontrei alguns resultados. A maioria funciona no Chrome, porém no IE 11 não. Como a aplicação precisa ser rodada no IE, por conta de não serem todos que possuem o Chrome na corporação, tinha que ser pelo IE mesmo.

Exemplo de código que funcionou no Chrome mas não no IE:

```
function doSearch(text) {
    if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
        document.designMode = "on";
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.collapse(document.body, 0);

        while (window.find(text)) {
            document.getElementById("button").blur();
            document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, "yellow");
            sel.collapseToEnd();
        }
        document.designMode = "off";
    } else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        while (textRange.findText(text)) {
            textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, "yellow");
            textRange.collapse(false);
        }
    }
}

<input type="text" id="search">
<input type="button" id="button" onmousedown="doSearch(document.getElementById('search').value)" value="Find">
```

Alguma ideia de algum código que funcione?

Comment: "encontrei alguns resultados", seria interessante dar exemplos. Querews que procure na página toda ou somente num campo em especial?

Comment: Ok, vamos lá à um exemplo que funcionou no Chrome mas não no IE:

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o código agora. E seria na página toda mesmo, são em torno de 1000 e poucas linhas, mas tudo texto, leve.

Comment: Ok, vou dar uma olhada daqui a pouco se ninguem fôr mais rápido. Uma duvida ainda: queres selecionar o texto para poder fazer copy/paster ou somente ter o texto como highlight?

Comment: Sergio, somente um highlight mesmo. O que for mais simples. Só para entender: é algumas pequenas informações que o usuário irá buscar na página, digamos por exemplo, um telefone de contato. Aí para facilitar para eles, essa busca pulando já na linha correta com uma seleção ajudará eles à enxergarem o que precisam, somente isso.. Obrigado pela ajuda desde já!

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText, e aqui também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/45073/129. Tenho mais uma pergunta: o texto está em qualquer sitio da página ou dentro de HTML específico?

Comment: Não consegui compreender a relação dos dois links com o problema. Está na própria página mesmo.

Comment: Verifiquei que agora o IE negrita o resultado buscado, porém, não "move" a página até onde o elemento encontra-se.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29043/discussion-between-sergio-and-rodrigo-brf).